# Datagrid data binding fails

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, datagridview

I am trying to use looping to get some data and bind into existing `Gridview`

```
for (int i =0; i<datasetResult.Rows.Count; i++){
 //some code to retrieve data from DB
 //after retrieved i am trying to bound it into my datagrid but i failed

DataRow dr = datasetResult.Tables[0].Rows[i];

if(RetVal ==0){

dataGridView.DataSource = datasetResult.Table[0];
}

}
```

My result failed to append, the end result is the last data row of my retrieved data
this is because every-time when there are new input it will only bind for once but never append, the second result will replaced the first result.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to retrieve the data inside the `for loop` and that's not the proper way.
Assuming you have **data** already in your `DataTable` and This one line of code will work for you.

`dataGridView.DataSource = datasetResult.Table[0];`

Comment: i need to use the loop result to populate my next result =(

Comment: what are you trying to do? from the `DataTable` to `DataGridView` or `DataGridView` to `DataTable`?

Comment: use the forloop result(from table A) to retrieve data from datatable (Table b) and bind to datagridview

Comment: hows is your data looks like?

Comment: u means my output data? the data keep replacing until end of the loop, so in the end i can only get one row of result.

Comment: i mean.. where was the origin of the data?

Comment: input data from dataTable A , after i got a list of data from dataTable A then i am trying to use it to populate dataTable B result

Comment: can you rephrase your question, try to include the data from `dataTable A` and what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Should you not collect the data from TableA ... then cycle through to create collect from Table B. Put table B data into a collection then bind to datagridview